# What is the replacement for the deprecated PeerConnection API?

Tags: html, websocket, p2p, webrtc

PeerConnection API was deprecated. Do you know its replacement?

I am using webRTC to connect two video streams from different locations. I want to use PeerConncetion API (or another reliable technology).

The most recent news on Google Chrome's blog links to examples which no longer work due to the deprecation. http://www.webrtc.org/blog/peerconnectionisnowdeprecatedpeerconnection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name is changing to RTCPeerConnection: see the [WebRTC blog](http://www.webrtc.org/blog/apiupdatedtoreflectlatesteditorsdraft).

Chrome Canary currently supports webkitRTCPeerConnection: take a look at the  [apprtc.appspot.com](http://apprtc.appspot.com) example.

Comment: Thanks Sam. So using RTCPeerConnection will only work on the Beta / Canary for Chrome. Is there anyway I can use a PeerConnection on the current latest release of Chrome? (22.0... instead of 23 like the current Beta)

Comment: I just checked on www.simpl.info/peerconnection in Chrome 22.0...: webkitPeerConnection00 works, but not webkitRTCPeerConnection (even though you'll find webkitRTCPeerConnection if you check in the console). In other words, you can set up a peer connection in Chrome Stable (also try http://apprtc.appspot.com). In 22.0... PeerConnection must be enabled in chrome://flags.